# How can I implement a custom selection in the forge viewer v7?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I tried to implement custom selection, referring to the forge blog.

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-window-selection-forge-viewer-part-i

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-window-selection-forge-viewer-part-ii

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-window-selection-forge-viewer-part-iii

https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/tree/master/src/client/components/Viewer/Extensions/Dynamic/Viewing.Extension.SelectionWindow

However, these codes only seem to fit into older versions of the viewer.

Is there a sample written for v7?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a more up-to-date tutorial on window selection: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-window-selection-forge-viewer-simpler-extension. Please try that one instead.

Comment: I wanted to point out a small error in that post. The second to last line of the code has `MySelectionWindow.prototype.varructor` instead of `MySelectionWindow.prototype.constructor`. I'm guessing a slightly overzealous search and replace of `const` to `var`. :-)

Comment: No no, `varructor` is actually a new keyword planned for ECMAScript 2021, representing a constructor that can possibly change during runtime.

Comment: Just kidding of course :D You're right! We'll get that fixed.